# Handling id token expiration?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web

On my project, when a user signs in, on auth changed is triggered and getIdToken is called then the token is sent by an HTTP post to the backend server where it gets verfied and then used as a cookie.
Then this cookie is reverfied and used each time the user requests a private page to verify his identity & access.

This keeps working untill the id token is expired. At this point, it fails and I can't find a way to use the newly generated token as a cookie.

Comment: can't you just delete the old cookie and give a new one? What server side framework are you using to set the cookie in the first place?

Comment: I'm using express.js, the main problem is sending the new one to to server since I cant find a way to listen to new token generation event

Answer (score 0):

It works now as following..

Backend auth check:

```
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.token)
  {
    return res.redirect("login");
  }
  else{
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.session.token).then(function(decodedToken) {
      req.session.uid = decodedToken.uid
      next();
    }).catch(function(error) { // expired token
      return res.render("refreshToken");
    });
  }
}
```

refreshToken rendered to client:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        fetch("/refreshToken",{method: "POST",body:"newToken="+idToken, headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}}).then(function(response){
          if(response.ok){
              location.reload(true)
          }
        })
        .then(function(data){
          if(data.suc == 0){
            window.location.replace("/login");
          }
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
    });
  }
  else{
    window.location.replace("/login");
  }
```

Back to backend:

```
app.post("/refreshToken", function(req, res){
  if(!req.session.uid) return res.send({suc:0});
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.newToken || "").then(function(decodedToken) {
    if(req.session.uid == decodedToken.uid){
      req.session.token = req.body.newToken;
      return res.send({suc:1});
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      res.send({suc:0});
  });
});
```